# Set user-wide network proxy settings on Ubuntu (without restart)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, proxy, network-interface

Is there any reliable way to set proxy settings **user-wide** for **all traffic** on Ubuntu?
As far I'm using `{http|https|ftp}_proxy` variables in `/home/$USER/.bashrc` which is nice but there's some issues:

- Many applications don't respect those settings, especially custom scripts
- Restart is required to apply changes.
- Doesn't work with scripts where commands are not executed in bash

I need **all traffic** to go through proxy and it have to be user-wide which means I have to be able to setup different proxies for each system user profile.
What comes to my mind is iptables or network-interfaces configuration but I'm not sure and I don't know how :)

Comment: A restart shouldn't be required, but logging in and logging out to reload them. If you want to set them system-wide look at `/etc/profile`

Comment: @SailorCire Yes, it can be performed even without logout/in just by executing `. ~/.bashrc` but that's not such an issue. Actually the only issue is 1 & 3. And I don't want it system wide. It should be possible to have many logged in users at the same time, using different proxies.

Comment: So this is a follow up to your earlier [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171830/route-vpn-traffic-through-different-proxies) :)

Answer (score 0):

A system-wide proxy, one that does not depend on environmental variables, can be set up using iptables and a proxy daemon such as polipo or squid. It's called [transparent proxy](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-2.html).